# Hyperlink to file in the same folder, EPPlus C#

Tags: c#, hyperlink, epplus

I am using EPPlus library in c#. 
I am trying to add a hyperlink in an Excel file that leads to a file in the current path. but I cannot write the full path because it is a downloadable folder. that means it depends on the location of the folder in the client.

I used this code:

```
using (ExcelRange rng = ws.Cells[i, 1])
{
    rng.Hyperlink = new Uri("file://.\\sss.jpg");
    rng.Value = p.Name;
}
```

But I am receiving an error from the Uri line:

> Not a valid Uri

Anybody has an Idea how can I write a link to a file in the same folder?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
using (ExcelRange rng = ws.Cells[i, 1])
{
    rng.Hyperlink = new Uri("sss.jpg", UriKind.Relative);
    rng.Value = p.Name;
}
```

This creates a relative URI.  I've tested this with EPPlus and it indeed looks for the file relative to the location of the Excel workbook.